# Index Integer Substring of Varchar ID PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing

I am going to be creating a very large table (320k+ rows) that I am going to be doing many complicated operations on so performance is very important. Each row will be a reference to a page / entity from an external site that already has unique IDs. In order to keep the data easy to read and for consistency reasons I would rather use those external IDs as my own row IDs, however the problem is that the IDs are in the format of `XXX########` where the `XXX` part is always the same identical string prefix and the second `########` part is a completely unique number. From what I know, using varchar ids is measurably slower performance wise, and only looking at the numerical part will have the same results.

What is the best way to do this? I still want to be able to do queries like `WHERE ID = 'XXX########'` and have the actual correct ids displayed in result sets rather than trimmed ones. Is there a way to define getters and setters for a column? Or is there a way to create an index that is a function on just the numerical part of the id?

Answer (score 1):

Since your ID column (with format `XXX########`) is a primary key, there will already be an index on that column.  If you wish to create an index based on the "completely unique number" portion of the ID, it is possible to create an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) in Postgres:

```
CREATE INDEX pk_substr_idx ON mytable (substring(id,4));
```

This will create an index on the `########` portion of your column.  However, bear in mind that the values stored in the index will be text, not numbers.  Therefore, you might not be able to see any real benefit to having this index around (i.e., you'll only be able to check for equality `=` and not comparison `>`/`<`/`>=`/`<=`.

The other drawback of this approach is that for every row you insert, you'll be updating two indexes (the one for the PK, and the one for the substring).

Therefore, if at all possible, I would recommend splitting your ID into separate prefix (the `XXX` portion) and id_num (the `########` portion) columns.  Since you stated that "the `XXX` part is always the same identical string prefix", you would stand to reap a performance benefit by either 1) splitting the string into two columns or 2) hard-code the `XXX` portion into your app (since it's "always the same identical string prefix") and only store the numeric portion in the database.

Another approach (if you are willing to split the string into separate `prefix` and `id_num` columns) is to create a composite index.  The table definition would then look something like:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
prefix text,
id_num int,
<other columns>,
PRIMARY KEY (prefix, id_num)
);
```

This creates a primary key on the two columns, and you would be able to see your queries use the index if you write your application with two columns in mind.  Again, you would need to split the ID up into text and number portions.  I believe this is the only way to get the best performance out of your queries.  Any value that mixes text and numbers will ultimately be stored and interpreted as text.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)

Answer (score -1):

Use an `IDENTITY` type column for the primary key and load the external IDs as a separate column